# Not getting a continuous video output from webcam in openCV

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am new to OpenCV and I am trying to render video from my webcam but instead of getting a continuous live video, I get a single frame as a picture. When I tap on close button it shows me the next frame as a picture.

```
import cv2
vid=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(vid.isOpened()):
    ret,frame=vid.read()
    cv2.imshow('Video',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF ==ord('e'):
        break
vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am using Asus X507uf laptop. Maybe it is my webcam's fault.

Comment: change  if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF ==ord('e'):        to                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF ==ord('e'):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code -

```
import cv2
vid=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(vid.isOpened()):
    ret,frame=vid.read()
    cv2.imshow('Video',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF ==ord('e'):
        break
   
vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```